# RavenDb faceted search predicate duplication

Tags: ravendb, faceted-search

Given I have the following class

```
class Car { 
    public string Id;
    public string Make;
    public string Model;
    public double Price;
    public IEnumerable<string> Locations;
}
```

my requirements are to retrieve a result set to the user and display some facets over it, for criteria that is captured in the following statement below.

```
session.Query<Car>()
    .Where(c => c.Make == "Mazda")
    .Where(c => c.Price < 3000)
    .Where(c => c.Locations.Any(l => l.In("VIC", "NSW")))
.ToList();
```

Given the above statement retrieves the result set, ideally without changing how I build my predicate if I want to retrieve facets I would have done

```
session.Query<Car, Car_Facets>()
    .Where(c => c.Make == "Mazda")
    .Where(c => c.Price < 3000)
    .Where(c => c.Locations.Any(l => l.In("VIC", "NSW")))
.ToFacets("facets/CarFacets");
```

where in I am not modifying the actual predicate and only changing what index to go to, and the ToFacets extension.

and my index would look like this

```
public class Car_Facets : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Car> {  
    public Car_Facets() {
        Map = cars => from car in cars 
                              select new { car.Make, car.Model, car.Price, car.Locations};
    }
}
```

this will not work. my facets come back empty. To get facets for the given query requirement my query needs to be modified to look like

```
session.Query<Car, Car_Facets>().AsProjection<CarOnLocation>
   .Where(c => c.Make == "Mazda")
   .Where(c => c.Price < 3000)
   .Where(c => c.Location.In("VIC", "NSW"))
.ToFacets("facets/CarFacets");
```

where the location property has been flattened out. the respective index being

```
public class Car_Facets : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Car> {  
    public Car_Facets() {
        Map = cars => from car in cars 
                      from location in car.Locations
                      select new {car.Make, car.Model, car.Price, Location = location};
    }
}
```

**some background**:
for the sake of simplicity I have specified the predicate as where clauses in my above query statements. In my application code, I have each predicate individually defined in Specification classes, using ioc I retreive all specifications satisfying a given interface and then build the expression from all specifications and finally apply the predicate from the expression to the query above. This gives me the compositional model where if we have requirements where a new predicate needs to be added, a new spec class can be created, and it will be picked up by the ioc and applied without any modification to any other classes

**the problem**
but I cannot do this any more as I have illustrated above in code, where my predicate changes when querying to nested collections when retrieving facets. Hence I have to define those predicates twice, or write them in two places, one for the result set query, and another for the facet query. If requirements change, I will need to update queries in two places.

**the question**
Is there a way I can work around this so that I can re use the same predicates for retrieving both result sets and facets when nested collection criteria is involved?

It will be great if for the same requirements I don't have to write queries in two different ways, one for retrieving results, and one for retrieving facets.